# laravel composer update error with database

Tags: laravel, config

I was installing a laravel project which was designed by myself. After I clone the code from github,I ran composer update.After the git terminal shows "artisan package:discover",it give an error:

> In Connection.php line 664:
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost'
>   (using pa   ssword: NO) (SQL: select * from `configs`)

I know the error is because a file in App\Providers\ConfigServiceProvider,in the boot method there is a line: 
`config(Config::all()->pluck('value','name')->toArray());`
Maybe this was excuted before I configure the database.I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid this error when I install the project.This method is for pulling the web configrations from database so that I can use it everywhere with config function. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use a try catch exception on the call itself.

```
try {
    config(Config::all()->pluck('value','name')->toArray());
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    \Log::info("Database connection not established");
}
```

If there is a connection, it will run everything as it should. But if there is an error, it will simply log the error.

Comment: maybe this is a solution

Comment: Thankyou, a simple solution didn't came to my mind. i always use try catch in situations such like this in my code but for this problem i went on searching on google. Not sure if there is a better alternative or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit `.env` file and set database credentials, make sure that your database user has the right to access configs table

Comment: you mean I should update the .env before I ran composer update?

Comment: Yes exactly, I think `.env` file is setting to an old database configuration

Comment: why this boot method was called before the project was installed?